# How to append a missing value to a python list?

Tags: python

Could anyone here tell me how to properly append series of missing values onto a python list?

for example,

```
 > ls=[1,2,3]
 > ls += []*2
 > ls
  [1,2,3]
```

but this is not the outcome I want. I want:

```
   [1,2,3, , ]
```

where the blanks denotes for the missing values.

(note: also what I DON'T want is:

```
   > ls
   [1,2,3,'','']
```

)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.

```py
>>> ls=[1,2,3]
>>> ls += ['']*2
[1, 2, 3, '', '']
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I have a slightly different question. How can I make my `ls` to be just [1,2,3, , ], not [1,2,3,' ',' ']? thank you.

Comment: @HDB you can't, python will always fill it.

Answer (score 0):

use `list.extend`, it will Extend list by appending elements from the iterable.

```
ls=[1,2,3]
ls.extend(['']*2)
```

output

```
 [1,2,3,'', '']
```

whereas `list.append` Append object to the end of the list.

ie `[1,2,3].extend([4])` - > `[1,2,3,4]`

```
`[1,2,3].extend([[4]])` -> `[1,2,3,[4]]`
```